# CSS is not apply in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

In Chrome and other browsers this works fine, but in Firefox it's not. 
In firefox it's show me "Edit" text and Image also. I just want to show Edit image.

## HTML Code

```
<td align="center">
<a id="lnkEdit" class="RemoveDecoration" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lnkEdit','')">
<img id="imgEdit" class="EditImage" style="border-style:None;" alt="Edit" src="">
</a>
</td>
```

## My CSS:

```
.EditImage a{
    background-image:url(../Images/Edit.png) ;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:14px;
    width:13px;
    background-position:-20px -3px;
    border:none;
     }  .EditImage:hover {
    background-image:url(../Images/Edit.png) ;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:14px;
    width:14px;
    background-position  : -2px -2px;
    border:none;
     }
```

See Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is showing "Edit" because the src="" attribute of the image tag is empty. So it shows the alternate (alt=) text.

The background-image is litterally in the background, so the

Bad empty src=""

```
<img id="imgEdit" class="EditImage" style="border-style:None;" alt="Edit" src="">
```

do that instead:

```
<img id="imgEdit" class="EditImage" style="border-style:None;" alt="Edit" src="../Images/Edit.png">
```

and remove the background-image attribute in the CSS

Comment: Hi I am using asp:grid, and using img inside linkbutton, I am not adding src anywhere

Comment: Use ImageButton http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx

Comment: You're probably not using ImageButton correctly http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_imagebutton.asp